# Memory issue downloding a large file

Tags: objective-c, ipad, memory, download

I have a big issue that I can't solve.
I'm making an iPad app & downloading a zip file in it (large one, like 80Mb) & at some point, like 75%, the app is crashing...
I executed profile & i can see how the memory is growing with the downloading, so, it is clearly a memory issue. 
My question is , how can I solve this properly? can I release some of this memory in some way.
Tell me if I need to put some source code here & thank u in advance!
Regards!

Answer (score 3):

Don't keep the downloaded bytes in memory but write them to disk in the order that you receive them in. If you don't know how, [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) can help you.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `NSOutputStream` and write it to the disk directly instead of keeping it in the memory till complete download. This approach will reduce the usage of runtime memory and will resolve your crashing issue.

look at this method in the API reference

```
+ (id)outputStreamToFileAtPath:(NSString *)path append:(BOOL)shouldAppend
```

Here is some reference on Streams:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This is great! but I forgot to tell you that I need to unfile it, & need to use the memory for that.
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Oscar: what do you mean by "unfile it"?  Can you do the operation in say 4kB blocks?

Comment: Sorry, Unzip it... I was confused by my sort English level, ;)